# Storm parallel understanding

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-storm

I have already read related materials about storm parallel but still keep something unclear. Suppose we take Tweets processing as an example. Generally what we are doing is retrieving tweets streaming, counting numbers of words of each tweets and write the numbers into a local file.

My question is how to understand the value of the parallelism of spouts as well as bolts. Within the function of builder.setSpout and builder.setBolt we can assign the parallel value. But in the case of word counting of tweets is it correct that only one spout should be set? More than one spouts are regarded as copies of the first same spout by which identical tweets flow into several spouts. If that is the case what is the value of setting more than one spouts?

Another unclear point is how to assign works to bolts? Is the parallel mechanism achieve in the way of Storm will find currently available bolts to process a next emitting spout? I revise the basic tweets counting code so the final counting results will be written into a specific directory, however, all results are actually combined in one file on nimbus. Therefore after processing data on supervisors all results will be sent back to nimbus. If this is true what is the communication mechanism between nimbus and supervisors?

I really want to figure out those problems!!! Do appreciate for the help!!

Comment: I don't understand your last question: "I revise the basic tweets counting code so the final counting results will be written into a specific directory, however, all results are actually combined in one file on nimbus. Therefore after processing data on supervisors all results will be sent back to nimbus. If this is true what is the communication mechanism between nimbus and supervisors?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the parallelism for spouts larger than one, required that the user code does different things for different instances. Otherwise (as you mentioned already), data is just sent through the topology twice. For example, you can have a list of ports you want to listen to (or a list of different Kafka topics). Thus, you need to ensure, that different instanced listen to different ports or topics... This can be achieved in `open(...)` method by looking at topology metadata like own task ID, and dop. As each instance has a unique ID, you can partition your ports/topics such that each instance picks different ports/topics from the overall list.

About parallelism: this depends on the connection pattern you are using when pluging your topology together. For example, using `shuffleGrouping` results in a round robin distribution of your emitted tuples to the consuming bolt instances. For this case, Storm does not "look" if any bolt instance is available for processing. Tuples are simply transfered and buffered at the receiver if necessary.

Furthermore, Nimbus and Supervisor only exchange meta data. There is not dataflow (ie, flow of tuples) between them.

Comment: I think I understand the first point of setting parallelism of spouts. And thank you for mentioning shuffleGrouping method, I didn't realize in this case storm will not look for an available bolt for the processing. I will check other grouping methods. And about my second question, what I was doing is in bolts it will write the processing results to a specific directory like /home/storm/Results.txt. Yesterday I thought the processing results in supervisor machines would also be sent back to Results.txt file on nimbus machine.

Comment: I was not sure how nimbus machine will get final processing results from bolts in supervisor machines.

Comment: Storm does not provide a load balance connection pattern as you like to have it. Why do you expect shuffleGrouping not to work for you?

Comment: Nibmus will not receive any data from bolts. You need to care of your final result by yourself in your sink bolts...

Comment: Since I thought Storm provides a grouping method that spouts will assign works to those available bolts.

Comment: So if nimbus can not receive any data from bolts, I should find the processing results saved in supervisor machines when specifying a directory like /home/storm/Results in the end of bolts. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. It will be local to the supervisor that executes the sink bolt.

Comment: Thank you for your patient replies!! It helps a lot. But since I don't have enough reputation value I can't vote for the answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: You are welcome. If you like, you can still vote later when you can vote. Can you mark answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases like "Kafka's Consumer Group" you have queue behaviour - which means that if one consumer read from the queue, other consumer will read different message from the queue. 
This will distribute read load from the queue across all workers.
In those cases you can have multiple spout reading from the queue

Comment: So we can take it as a vivid scene where the constant source like real-time tweets takes the role of a pool of water while spouts take the roles of pipe. The parallelism mechanism here is we want to pump more water in a unit time so more than one spouts are required to process them.